# Auto-Hide Nav Trigger Second Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the code structured for an `navBar` that auto hides/appears as you scroll down/up.

I am attempting to trigger a second element (`#floatingBox`) to shift up `10px` when the nav is hidden, and shift down `10px` when it reappears. The rest of the time, I want the `#floatingBox` to be fixed and "follow" the user as they scroll.

***Problem***

`#floatingBox` will follow, but will not shift its top, even when I add/remove the class.

I am clearly missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Link: https://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/ZKbRyG

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navBarHeight = $("header").outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event)
         {
 didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function()
      {
 if(didScroll)
 {
  hasScrolled();
  didScroll = false;
 }
}, 100);


function hasScrolled()
{
 var st = $(this).scrollTop();
 
 if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
  return;
 
 if(st > lastScrollTop && st > navBarHeight)
 {
  $('header').removeClass("nav-down").addClass("nav-up");
  $("floatingBox").removeClass("box-start").addClass("up");
 }
 else
 {
  if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height())
  {
   $("header").removeClass("nav-up").addClass("nav-down");
   $("floatingBox").removeClass("up").addClass("box-start");
  }
 }
 lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body
{
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header
{
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up
{
    top: -40px;
}

main
{
  background-color: #f2f2f2; 
 height: 2000px;
}

#floatingBox
{
 height: 230px;
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 position: fixed;
 top: 100px;
 left: 30px;
 transition: top .2s ease;
}

#floatingBox.up
{
 top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down"></header>
<main>
 <div id="floatingBox" class="box-start"></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems, I think.

First, in your jQuery function for `floating-box` you need to change it to `#floating-box`.

Second, assuming you want to revert to original conditions when scrolling back up, you need to reverse the order of classes being removed and added on `floating-box`--> `$("#floatingBox").removeClass("up").addClass("box-start");`

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navBarHeight = $("header").outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event)
         {
 didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function()
      {
 if(didScroll)
 {
  hasScrolled();
  didScroll = false;
 }
}, 100);


function hasScrolled()
{
 var st = $(this).scrollTop();
 
 if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
  return;
 
 if(st > lastScrollTop && st > navBarHeight)
 {
  $('header').removeClass("nav-down").addClass("nav-up");
  $("#floatingBox").removeClass("box-start").addClass("up");
 }
 else
 {
  if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height())
  {
   $("header").removeClass("nav-up").addClass("nav-down");
   $("#floatingBox").removeClass("up").addClass("box-start");
  }
 }
 lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body
{
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header
{
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up
{
    top: -40px;
}

main
{
  background-color: #f2f2f2; 
 height: 2000px;
}

#floatingBox
{
 height: 230px;
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 position: fixed;
 top: 100px;
 left: 30px;
 transition: top .2s ease;
}

#floatingBox.up
{
 top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down"></header>
<main>
 <div id="floatingBox" class="box-start"></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Fixed it! You rock!